# How to detect fullscreen mode of AVPlayerViewController in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa, ios8.3

How to check whether video is play full screen mode or not in `AVPlayerViewController`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the duplicate answer will helps you

Comment: But brother i want answer in objective c not in swift #Karthik

Comment: is easy to convert , you need the exact answer